# How to show the index and end of the Flatlist by 15 items on every click

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I need to show the index and bottom of the list while click on the up and down button.

Is any option to show only 15 items up or down If I click on the up or down arrow.

For Eg) Consider a list has 500 items. It has an up and down arrow. If I click on the down arrow once I need to show only 15 items for the first time and If click on the down arrow next need to show the next 15 items.

Also If I click on the up arrow it needs to show 15 items above not all

In this usecase I need to move up and down of the screen. Any option to modify the scrollToIndex and scrollToEnd in Flatlist to achieve this use case

```
   upButtonHandler = () => {
        //OnCLick of Up button we scrolled the list to top
        this.ListView_Ref.scrollToOffset({ offset: 0,  animated: true });
      };

   downButtonHandler = () => {
    //OnCLick of down button we scrolled the list to bottom
     this.ListView_Ref.scrollToEnd({ animated: true });
    };

 <TouchableOpacity
    activeOpacity={0.5}
      onPress={this.downButtonHandler}
      style={styles.downButton}>
      <Image
        source={{uri:'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AboutReact/sampleresource/master/arrow_down.png',
        }}
        style={styles.downButtonImage}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity
      activeOpacity={0.5}
      onPress={this.upButtonHandler}
      style={styles.upButton}>
      <Image
        source={{uri:'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AboutReact/sampleresource/master/arrow_up.png',
        }}
        style={styles.upButtonImage}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `slice` the data provided to the `FlatList` every time a button is pressed.As the FlatList is a pure Component you need to pass a `extra` prop to re render the FlatList after button is pressed

Maintain a state variable such as section which describes which part of data to display like (0,15),(15,30),...

Update this variable inside the up and down buttons,taking care of the boundaries so as not to get bad results.This is easily solved by wrapping `setState` inside a if condition so it will look roughly as

```
updateSectionLow = () => {
    const { section } = this.state;
    if (section > 0) {
      this.setState({
        section: section - 1,
      });
    }
  };
  updateSectionHigh = () => {
    const { section, data } = this.state;
    if (data.length > (section + 1) * 15) {
      this.setState({
        section: section + 1,
      });
    }
  };
```

and the FlatList looks like this

```
<FlatList
   data={this.state.data.slice(this.state.section*15,(this.state.section+1)*15)}
   renderItem={({ item }) => {
            return (
              <View style={styles.row}>
                <Text>{item.data}</Text>
              </View>
            );
   }}
   extraData={this.state.section}
/>
```

Here is a working expo [demo](https://snack.expo.io/@karthik.01/flatlist-items-15)

**EDIT**
After having discussion with the OP person,i have changed my code little bit.

Get the offset after scroll,
for a vertical list

```
onMomentumScrollEnd={e => this.scroll(e.nativeEvent.contentOffset)}
```

Inside the handler

```
this.setState({
  index: Math.floor(offset.y / (ITEM_HEIGHT+SEPARATOR_HEIGHT)),
});
```

if there is no separator then you can put `SEPARATOR_HEIGHT` to be 0

and it is only matter of using scrollToOffset with ref as follows

for going down the list by ITEMS_DISP(like 15)

```
this.flatListRef.scrollToOffset({
    offset:(this.state.index+ITEMS_DISP)*ITEM_HEIGHT+(this.state.index+ITEMS_DISP)*SEPARATOR_HEIGHT
  });
```

for going top the list by some ITEMS_DISP

```
this.flatListRef.scrollToOffset({
    offset:(this.state.index-ITEMS_DISP)*ITEM_HEIGHT+(this.state.index-ITEMS_DISP)*SEPARATOR_HEIGHT
  });
```

Updated demo [link](https://snack.expo.io/@karthik.01/flatlist-items-15)

Comment: Here I have a question. The data is rendered already in the screen and then I need the move up and down as I mentioned in my question, For this case how can I scroll this. In your example it rendering by 15 and again 15 not first rendered all the data

Comment: ok first you render all data and then on button click you move to the next 15 top/bottom items right?.

Comment: Yes, first I render items by using pagination. After this, I will scroll up or down. That's why I have used scrollToIndex and scrollToEnd here.

Comment: If you can get the size of your rendered row and the offset of the scrollview you can know which item is at top of the list i.e,index of item and then its just applying logic for checking the bounds of the list like if each item's height is 40 and there are a total of 25 items and if the offset of the list is 400 then you are at the 10th item and if 400+15*40 < list-total-items*40 then scrollto (x or y to 400+15*40) and same goes for going top.Try this once.

Comment: Can you able to give any working examples for this calculation

Comment: in that case is the scroll disabled? after clicking on top and bottom button

Comment: Scroll is always enabled

Comment: If the top item has index2 then onclicking down button what item should come on top?17?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If click up from index 17 then needs to show the index 2. Also is there is any option to find the cursor is in which position in flatlist

Comment: @sejn i think i have implemented the output like you have asked,please verify from the demo link.Cheers!

Comment: I have a question while click on got to bottom. For first time if I load the data from the cache with pagination. So, in the end, it again scrolls and shows an empty screen.

Comment: But while scrolling to the bottom the offset is not known. And it adding the white space at the end of the screen for each click on the down. Up is working fine for me

Comment: How can I calculate the getItemLayout prop  for the above?

Comment: AFIK you have to provide the dimensions of each item for a better performance.

Comment: I have gave the width and heght of my elements